# Use shell script parameter inside awk command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How do you use a command line parameter in an awk command? The parameter is in the variable $2:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get lines from file
grep -i "" $1|    

# Print out lines where first column element is greater than $2
awk '{
    if($1 > "'$2'")
        print $0;
}'
```

The if statement is true when it shouldn't be, e.g 3 > 20 so I think I'm referencing it incorrectly.

Comment: Just get rid of the double quote layer. It's otherwise comparing strings `$1 > '$2'` (and `'3' > '20'` is true). So do: `if ($1 > '$2')`.

Comment: @lurker followed the duplicate answer and used  awk -v threshold="$2"

Comment: @lurker that works....i tried that so many times and now it works....getting trolled by bash